# MySQL SELECT row based on prefix

Tags: mysql, select

Im attempting to do a SELECT on data in a table that contains prefixes, and I have the "keyword".

So unlike a normal search where the prefix/keyword is contained in the row data, and that the prefix/keyword is shorter (or contained in) a possible row of data.

This is the opposite. If have prefixes in rows and I want to find the best matching row based on the (longer) word/phase.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, keyCode VARCHAR(45) NULL, Username VARCHAR(45) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO table1(keyCode,Username)VALUES('123','Peter')
INSERT INTO table1(keyCode,Username)VALUES('456','Paul')
INSERT INTO table1(keyCode,Username)VALUES('1234','John')
```

Now let's say the phrase I have been given is longer than the prefix in the data.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE keyCode LIKE '123456%';
```

I know this will not work, but I would like to return the Row with User 'John'.

How? 
(I can use stored procedures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may phrase your `LIKE` expression in the reverse order:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE '123456' LIKE CONCAT(keyCode, '%');
```

This would compare, for example, `'123456'` against `'1234%'`, which should be a match in this case.

Comment: Oh, wow, so simple... Its coming back with Peter first, then John... how do I get it to order according to the "best match"?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/quENZbt67pQzHDa6z4ptHP/0

Comment: I think I got it: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE '123456' LIKE CONCAT(keyCode, '%') ORDER BY LENGTH(keyCode) DESC;`

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the existence of the `keyCode` prefix at the beginning of your string using [`LOCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate).  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE LOCATE(keyCode,'123456') = 1;
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/quENZbt67pQzHDa6z4ptHP/0

Comment: @Conrad Using `LIKE`, `LOCATE`, or `INSTR` all should have similar performance (I think).

Comment: @Conrad - Out of curiosity, I just ran a couple of checks on a table with 50k+ rows and both appear to be equally performant.

Comment: I don't anticipate there being more then a few thousands rows in any case.